# JavaScript is not fired! ODOO

Tags: javascript, odoo

I've created a basic module for testing my .js function, but I don't know why it isn't firing? This is the architecture of my module:

```
a_js
 |static
     |src
        |js
          a_js.js
 |view
   |a_js_view.xml
   |call.xml
 |__init__.py
 |__openerp__.py
 |a_js.py
```

This are my files:

`a_js/__init__.py`

```
import a_js
```

Here is my `a_js/__openerp__.py`

```
#a_js/__openerp__.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
'name': 'Pruebas JS',
    'version': '0.1',
    'website' : '',
    'category': '',
    'summary': '',
    'description': """ - """,
    'author': 'JS',
    'depends': [
    'base',
    'web',
    ],
    'data': [
    "view/a_js_view.xml",
    "view/call.xml",
    ],
        'demo': [
    ],
    'test': [
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

My `a_js/a_js.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models,fields,api
class a_js(models.Model):    
    _name="a.js"
    numeros = fields.Integer('Números')
    letras = fields.Char('Letras')
    tiempo = fields.Date('Fecha')
```

My `a_js/view/a_js_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <menuitem name="JS" id="js_root_menu"/>
        <menuitem name="JS" parent="js_root_menu" id="js_menu"/>
        <record id="a_js_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">a.js.form</field>
            <field name="model">a.js</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Invoice">
                    <header>
                    </header>
                    <sheet string="Datos">
                        <label string="Datos de Prueba" />
                        <field name="numeros" class="id_num"/>
                        <field name="letras"/>
                        <field name="tiempo"/>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
         </record>

        <record id="a_js_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">         
            <field name="res_model">a.js</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="name">JS</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>
        <menuitem name="JS" parent="js_menu"  action="a_js_action" id="a_js_menu"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Here is my `a_js/view/call.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="a_js assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/a_js/static/src/js/a_js.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

And here is my `a_js/static/src/js/a_js.js` file:

```
openerp.a_js = function(instance) {
var QWeb = openerp.web.qweb;
    _t = instance.web._t;
instance.web.FormView.include({
    on_loaded: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        $('.id_num').keypress(function isNumber(evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        return self._super(data);
    },
});
};
```

I want to only allow numbers entry in my `numeros` field, Why my js function is not fired? Please share with as some examples about how to do that, or a guideline please!

Answer (score 1):

Your script will be added in top of the assets,

```
<xpath expr="." position="inside">
```

So when you are doing this make sure view_form.js is already loaded before your script.

I think you need to do

```
<xpath expr="//script[@src='/web/static/src/js/view_tree.js']" position="after">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="your script file path"></script>
</xpath>
```

Another thing first check by putting alert function whether your script will be loaded or not, if it's loaded then put alert inside function whether it's calling or not.

Comment: "Your script will be added in top of the assets," that is why I make this lines `<template id="assets_backend" name="a_js assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend"><xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/a_js/static/src/js/a_js.js"></script></xpath>
        </template>`, in my `a_js/view/call.xml`, in what file I should put your advice, `<xpath expr="//script[@src='/web/static/src/js/view_tree.js']" position="after"> <script type="text/javascript" src="your script file path"></script></xpath>`, could you be more specific? please

Comment: When you write expr="." and position="inside" it will append your script very first to the template, not at the end so your script will be rendered before all the base script that is why script is not able to find the proper widget/class to extend or override methods. So you need to keep it after all the base script will be rendered.